# When can a process (with given uid/gid) write a file (with given user:group)?

Tags: permissions, group, chmod, ownership

I'm looking for a "logic statement" to know when file `hello.txt` owned by `user1:groupA` can be **written** by a process owned by `user2:groupB`.

I currently see only those cases:

1. the process can write it **if** `user2 == user1` (and file has `u+w` permission)
2. **or** if `groupB == groupA` (and `g+w` permission)
3. **or** if `user2` is a member of `groupA` (and `g+w` permission)
4. **or** if `hello.txt` has `o+w` permission
5. (the fact that `user1` is a member of `groupB` does **not** allow the file to 
   be written, is that right?)

**Are there other cases?**

---

Example: how to make

`/var/www/website1/hello.txt   user1:groupA   rwxrwx---` writable by Apache process (`uid:www-data, gid:www-data`)?

I currently see: **either**

```
chgrp www-data hello.txt
```

(tested: it works) **or**

```
adduser www-data user1
```

(i.e. add *user* `www-data` to the *group* `user1`; tested, it works; requires an Apache restart).

Is there another option? NB: adding user `user1` to the group `www-data` doesn't work, tested.

Answer (score 0):

If the file has write permission on everyone like `666` or something like that, any process could write to it.

As well if the process have strong permission like `root`, it can change the file permission and then write to it.

But your cases covers all the regular options